# Is there a way to do named subsetting with rowSums in R?

Tags: r

I used this question and answer to get what I want ([how to compute rowsums using tidyverse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43417530/how-to-compute-rowsums-using-tidyverse)), but I was wondering if there was a way to do named subsetting with `rowSums`. I can imagine an instance where I have a lot of variables where this would be desirable.

What I mean is something like this:

```
rosSums(iris, Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width)
```

Instead of:

```
rowSums(iris[1:2])
```

Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: `rowSums(iris[, c("Sepal.Length", "Sepal.Width")])`

Comment: or if you are trying to index columns like 1:2 `rowSums(iris[,c(grep("Sepal.Length",colnames(iris)):grep("Sepal.Width",colnames(iris)))])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using dplyr you could simply do.

```
iris %>% mutate(Sepal.Length + Sepal.Width)
```